# Best way for rendering geotools in web service

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, web-service, geotools

I'm using geotools in my web service project. I always thought geotools is somehow compatible with openlayers, but now when it actually came to implementing this functionality, i can't find even one example. Any other ideas, tools to do it? I've read that geoserver is using openlayers with geotools, but as i said i can't find any example,documentation.

Comment: have you looked at http://geoserver.org

Comment: Yes, but i don't think such details of implementation are described anywhere in documentation. Maybe i didn't make myself clear - i have some data manipulation done using geotools and now i want to display the output (featurecollection) in my web service

Comment: then look at how geoserver does it - it is open source you can read the code.